# How to launch settings on the first run of the app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have developed an Android app and it run effectively though I want launch the settings activity on the every first run (after installation) then for the rest of its life cycle, it should launch the main activity. How do I go about that?

Comment: set as launcher activity

Comment: Use SharedPreference for this, find the tutorial of sharedpref in this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the existing settings and launch the settings activity if they do not exist (files missing or shared preferences are not defined). Or, define a preference like `FIRST_RUN` with the default value true that you set to false on the first run.

See [Android storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) on how to remember settings on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Set it as the MainActivity and create a Shared Preference so it wont load every time the Application loads..

**MainActivity**

```
private final String KEY = "SHARED_KEY_FIRST_RUN"; 

public void onCreate() {

   SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPrefereneces(....,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   if(pref.getInteger(KEY,0) == 0) {

       //Do first Time Loading.
    }
   else {

       Intent intent = Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
     }

}
```

dont forget to declare the SecondActivity in the Mainfest and save the Key with `SharedPreferences.Editor`

Comment: You can also try if(!pref. contains(KEY)){\\app running first time code}... if key is found then it was launched before..... If key is not present then it was launched for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
private boolean isFirstTime()
{
    preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {

        // first time
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    return !ranBefore;
}
```

So, if you want to check:

```
if (isFirstTime()){

//if first time do something

}
```

Comment: You can also try this,
`if(!pref. contains(KEY)){
\\app running first time code} 
else
{ \\code with not running first time}`

If key is found then it was launched before..... If key is not present then it was launched for the first time.